# Continuous variables and marginal function

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Lets say we have random variables $X,Y$.

Density function

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1/2ye^{(-x-y^{2})/2}$  for $x>0$ and $y>0$.

Now our task is to find if random variables are indenpendant and find $E(X+Y)$.

We know that if $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x) * f_{Y}(y)$ random variables X and Y are indenpendant. To find $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ we need to integrate our density function.

However, we also know, that if we can transform $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = g(x) * h(y)$. Random variable X and Y are independant.

We see that

a ) $1/2ye^{(-x-y^{2})/2} = 1/2e^{-x/2} * ye^{-y^{2}/2}$ or

b ) $1/2ye^{(-x-y^{2})/2} = e^{-x/2} * 1/2ye^{-y^{2}/2}$

Which means random variables X and Y are indenpendant. However, in order to calculate $E(X+Y)$ we need to know $f_{X}(x)$ and $ f_{Y}(y)$ So we still have to integrate.

Is there a way how to decide $f_{X}(x)$ and $ f_{Y}(y)$ when we can transform function into $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = g(x) * h(y)$.? By definition they can differ by multiplicative constant.

Comment: You have successfully recognize the two kernels and you need to determine the normalizing constants - which you have no short cut in general and have to do integration as usual. Unless for some very famous family of distributions like exponential with pdf $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ that you can directly write down the constant from the parametrization you read from kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a probability density function must integrate to $1$. Since
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac12 e^{-\frac12 x}\ \mathsf dx = \int_0^\infty ye^{-\frac12 y^2}\ \mathsf dy = 1,
$$
we see that $f_X(x) = \frac12 e^{-\frac12 x}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, $f_Y(y)=ye^{-\frac12 y^2}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(y)$ is the correct choice of density functions. We compute
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty x\frac12 e^{-\frac12 x}\ \mathsf dx = 2
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E[Y] = \int_0^\infty y^2e^{-\frac12 y^2}\ \mathsf dy = \sqrt{\frac\pi 2},
$$
and hence
$$\mathbb E[X+Y] = \mathbb E[X] + \mathbb E[Y] = 2+\sqrt{\frac\pi2}.$$